# How to solve django error: raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-class-based-views, django-3.0

I am using Django 3+...

I am trying to render a template of the blog on my page, but I am receiving a error:

```
Internal Server Error: /postsblog
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projetos Dev\gpprofessional\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Projetos Dev\gpprofessional\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\Projetos Dev\gpprofessional\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "D:\Projetos Dev\gpprofessional\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "D:\Projetos Dev\gpprofessional\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 81, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "D:\Projetos Dev\gpprofessional\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 63, in resolve_template
    return select_template(template, using=self.using)
  File "D:\Projetos Dev\gpprofessional\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 47, in select_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: posts/blog.html, posts/post_list.html
[13/May/2020 22:57:09] "GET /postsblog HTTP/1.1" 500 93437
```

This error occurs when I try to access the blog URL.

I have some apps in my project like app base, app posts, app blog, and app categorias

My directory file to be looks like the image:

[image]

My files in app base: 
**urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('posts', include('posts.urls')),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls'))
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**views**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

My files in app posts:
**urls**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('blog', views.PostIndex.as_view(), name='post_blog'),
    path('categoria/<str:categoria>', views.PostCategoria.as_view(), name='post_categoria'),
    path('busca/', views.PostBusca.as_view(), name='post_busca'),
    path('post/<int:pk>', views.PostDetalhes.as_view(), name='post_detalhes'),
]
```

**views**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from .models import Post


class PostIndex(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/blog.html'


class PostBusca(PostIndex):
    pass


class PostCategoria(PostIndex):
    pass


class PostDetalhes(UpdateView):
    pass
```

My file settings in **TEMPLATES** and **INSTALLED_APPS** configuration it's looks like:

**TEMPLATES**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**ISTALLED_APPS**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'posts',
    'categorias',
    'comentarios',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'collectfast',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'base',
    'blog',
]
```

I tried to use the only folder for all templates but had the error. I think that the error to be in the URL base file, but I don't how to solve it. I made some searches on google but without success...

Comment: show us your settings  TEMPLATES variable and INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: I edited my post adding templates and installed_apps

Comment: you have posted only TEMPLATES :)

Comment: adjusted now, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add app in front on template name considering template loader goes through templates in all apps, so in your case

```
template_name = 'blog.html'
```

Comment: If I change, the new error happen...

```
    raise new from exc
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: base/base.html
```

Comment: Did you change something regarding this project template structure as you can notice error is same as for other templates if you remove base/ it would work ( or get you to another error). You can add additional top level directory and call it as your app name to avoid having to rename all of templates

Comment: Sorry, but, I don't understood... Only create a new directory and put the app base inside it to solve the problem?

Comment: no, create folder structure like following base/templates/base/ and put everything that was directly in base/templates in it ( you can do similar for other apps too)

Comment: Thanks my friend! the error happened because an include had an error. After adjusted, the template was rendered! The error occurred in file blog.html on include tag.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create this path - base\templates\base\task_list.html.(base = app name)

Then run these command(if you don't migrate):

- python3 manage.py makemigrations
- python3 manage.py migrate

Answer (score 0):

you can try template_name for your

````
path('profile/', views.PrivateDocumentCreateView.as_view(template_name="privatedocument_form.html"), name='profile'),
```app
````