# TemplateDoesNotExist Error Django not-defined template appers

Tags: python, django

First, I got an error message on web browser [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffi54.jpg).

It says,

'TemplateDoesNotExist at /

index.html, base/item_list.html'.

Console error message says,

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kgwtm\Desktop\Django\Django-Fujimoto\VegeKet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kgwtm\Desktop\Django\Django-Fujimoto\VegeKet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\kgwtm\Desktop\Django\Django-Fujimoto\VegeKet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\kgwtm\Desktop\Django\Django-Fujimoto\VegeKet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 81, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "C:\Users\kgwtm\Desktop\Django\Django-Fujimoto\VegeKet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 63, in resolve_template
    return select_template(template, using=self.using)
  File "C:\Users\kgwtm\Desktop\Django\Django-Fujimoto\VegeKet\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 47, in select_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: pages/index.html, base/item_list.html
[23/Feb/2022 16:19:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 83837
```

In the first place, I don't even create or declare 'base/item_list.html' in any file in Django project.

I've created 'config' project and 'base' app.

Project 'config' file organization [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCyJG.jpg).

App 'base' file organization [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMDZx.jpg).

config/urls.py here.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from base import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('', views.IndexListView.as_view()),
]
```

base/views/item_views.py here

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from base.models import Item


class IndexListView(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'pages/index.html'
```

base/views/**init**.py here.

```
from .item_views import *
```

So, templates/pages/index.html here.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
     
{% block main %}
 
{% for object in object_list %}
<p>
  <a href="/items/{{object.pk}}/">
    {{object.name}} - ¥{{object.price}}
  </a>
</p>
{% endfor %}
 
{% endblock %}
```

Just in case, models.py (in this case, models/item_models.py) here.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
import os


def create_id():
    return get_random_string(22)

def upload_image_to(instance, filename):
    item_id = instance.id
    return os.path.join('static', 'items', item_id, filename)

class Tag(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Category(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(default=create_id, primary_key=True, max_length=22,
                          editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(default='', max_length=50)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    sold_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='', blank=True,
                              upload_to=upload_image_to)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True
    )
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

models/**init**.py is as follows.

```
from .item_models import *
```

I think a similar problem is taken up in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61788115/how-to-solve-django-error-raise-templatedoesnotexist-jointemplate-name-li).

I don't have any clue about 'base/item_list.html'.

Would you please help me??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Elementary mistake.

I edited settings.py as follows.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'tamplates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

So, I should edit the line `'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'tamplates'],`

to `'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],`.